# What's the correct term for horizontally and vertically on a map?

Tags: single-word-requests

The horizontal (left-right) dimension is called longitude. The vertical (top-bottom) is called latitude. However, I'm not sure how to adjectivize and adverbize those terms.

The best shot expressing the meaning I can think of is "*latitude-wise*" for the vertical case. Here, I have two questions.

Is there a more sophisticated term for that? And if not...

What is the most recommended way to express the work-around of mine?
a. latitude-wise
b. latitudewise
c. latitude wise
d. latidudelly
e. lati-what-ever-else-combo-might-be-conceiveable

Of course, the same wonderings go for the horizontal dimension, i.e. "*longitude-wise*". However, I'd be strongly surprised if it differed in principle from the vertical one.

Comment: General Reference - [longitudinal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/longitudinal), [latitudinal](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=latitudinal&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=0). No reason why you can't append ***-ly*** to either.

Comment: It depends on what you're talking about. See Fillmore's lecture on [_Space_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/2-Space.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm talking about a geographical **map**, which by the definition is 2D. Your point, however, is valid - **some** map might be of the more abstract, mathematical kind. In this particular case, I was referring to that flat thing you can download using Bing Maps, though.   :)

Comment: Certainly, but even 2-D maps have overlays (thus becoming 2½-D); and it is not a given that `Top` on the map is `North` on the territory mapped, nor that parallels and meridians are consistently marked or even useful.

Comment: @JohnLawler You're once again very correct perforating my correction. Let's turn it around - I meant what a half-wit would intuitively assume to be the default. (Yes, I know... You can question "*half-wit*", "*intuitively*" etc. I'd give you +1 for nit-pickness if you'd answer.  :) )

Comment: Why, thank you. Nitpickiness is one of the things linguists are trained for -- in order to find the boundaries of a phenomenon and describe it accurately -- and after 50 years or so it's hard to avoid the instinct.

Comment: @JohnLawler I feel that I need to emphasize that, although the term "*nit-pick*" is generally regarded derogatory, I use it as one of the best qualities one can exhibit when discussing facts and hard issues. In my view, most of the problems in relations between people don't occur due to the difference of views but the failure to express and/or perceive the likeness of these. I meant that as a compliment (throwing in the towel, so to speak). It's hats off for you, friend. Hats off and thrown latidudinally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you have the terms reversed: latitude is a horizontal line and longitude is a vertical line.

As far as using them as adjectives and adverbs:

latitudinal (adj), latitudinally (adv)

longitudinal (adj), longitudinally (adv)

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Latitude_and_Longitude_of_the_Earth.svg) seems to disagree with your first statement.   :)   (Or, rather, the statement itself is correct down to the bones but the **vertical** direction on the map is equivalent to moving **accross** the latitudes, meaning that it's the latitudinal movement that takes you to the poles.)

Comment: I just realized a horrible, logical-excrement. While *latitude* is, as you very correctly pointed out, a **horizontal** entity, the *latitudinal* movement is very much a **vertical** occurrence. It'd be much more convenient if I was a sloppy, dumb individual unconcerned with exactness of the linguistic weirdifications. Then again, I'm a math post-grad.   :)